# An appropriate synonym for “skills” in this context?

Tags: synonyms

Which synonym, term or phrase can I use instead of 'skills' to create a sentence?

> I believe that my **skills** and strengths are an excellent match for your company profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most job descriptions list **skills**. There is probably little need to use a  word other than "skills" on a letter of interest or resume. You could use "abilities," but employers are looking for "skills" and they might not make the connection. Yes, there are some that lack that skill.